# Prevent deleting a tag in Subversion

Tags: svn

Does anyone know of a good script to prevent users from deleting a tag in Subversion?

Comment: Subversion wasn't built for that. Are you sure you have good reasons to not to rely on team members' cooperation?

Comment: ávio: Then you have very likely far worse problems than tags getting deleted (which can be reversed, after all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could do this with a pre-commit hook script on the server.  Take a look at the [example scripts](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/contrib/hook-scripts/) in the source.